# How to get Spyder to read directory path correctly

Tags: database, directory, path

I am trying to create and oversampling on atmospheric data from NASA. I am using the popy file from https://github.com/Kang-Sun-CfA/Oversampling_matlab/blob/master/popy.py and this is my current code

```
# directory where popy.py is
popy_dir = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Oversampling_matlab-master\Oversampling_matlab-master'
# directory where level 2 data are. may need to customize F_subset* to adapt different data     versions
l2_dir = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Oversampling_matlab-master\oversampling_matlab-master\OMH2O\L2'
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,popy_dir)
from popy_file import popy
import logging`
# show all logging information
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
# set spatial/temporal bounds
trop_CO = popy(instrum="TROPOMI",product="CO", grid_size=0.1,west=-76,east=-69,south=40,north=45,
start_year=2022,start_month=7,start_day=1,
end_year=2022,end_month=7,end_day=3,end_hour=23,end_minute=59,end_second=59)

trop_CO.F_subset_S5PCO(l2_dir)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`
# scatter plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',
llcrnrlat=40,urcrnrlat=45,
llcrnrlon=-76,urcrnrlon=-69)
 m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)`
# m.drawparallels(np.arange(-20., 20., 2.5), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
# m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180., 5.), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])
tmplon = trop_CO.l2g_data['lonc']-trop_CO.west
tmplon[tmplon < 0] = tmplon[tmplon < 0]+360
tmplon = tmplon+trop_CO.west
s = m.scatter(tmplon,trop_CO.l2g_data['latc'],
s=None,c=trop_CO.l2g_data['column_amount']*1e4/6.02e23*0.018)
m.colorbar(s,label='water vapor column [mm]')
plt.savefig('trop_CO_l2g.pdf')`
```

instead of correctly reading the path of the directory correctly spyder reads each letter individually. This is the error code I get

```
runfile('C:/Program Files (x86)/Oversampling_matlab-master/Oversampling_matlab-          master/Oversampling_code.py', wdir='C:/Program Files (x86)/Oversampling_matlab-  master/Oversampling_matlab-master')
Reloaded modules: popy_file
INFO:popy_file:creating an instance of popy
INFO:popy_file:Read, subset, and store level 2 data to l2g_data
INFO:popy_file:Loading C
 WARNING:popy_file:C gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'C'
INFO:popy_file:Loading :
WARNING:popy_file:: gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 22] Invalid argument: b':'
INFO:popy_file:Loading 
WARNING:popy_file:\ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'\\'
INFO:popy_file:Loading P
WARNING:popy_file:P gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'P'
INFO:popy_file:Loading r
WARNING:popy_file:r gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'r'
INFO:popy_file:Loading o
WARNING:popy_file:o gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'o'
INFO:popy_file:Loading g
WARNING:popy_file:g gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'g'
INFO:popy_file:Loading r
WARNING:popy_file:r gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'r'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading  
 WARNING:popy_file:  gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno -74] NetCDF: Malformed URL: b' '
INFO:popy_file:Loading F
WARNING:popy_file:F gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'F'
INFO:popy_file:Loading i
WARNING:popy_file:i gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'i'
INFO:popy_file:Loading l
WARNING:popy_file:l gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'l'
INFO:popy_file:Loading e
WARNING:popy_file:e gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'e'
INFO:popy_file:Loading s
WARNING:popy_file:s gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b's'
INFO:popy_file:Loading  
WARNING:popy_file:  gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno -74] NetCDF: Malformed URL: b' '
INFO:popy_file:Loading (
WARNING:popy_file:( gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'('
INFO:popy_file:Loading x
WARNING:popy_file:x gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'x'
INFO:popy_file:Loading 8
WARNING:popy_file:8 gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'8'
INFO:popy_file:Loading 6
WARNING:popy_file:6 gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'6'
INFO:popy_file:Loading )
WARNING:popy_file:) gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b')'
INFO:popy_file:Loading 
WARNING:popy_file:\ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'\\'
INFO:popy_file:Loading O
WARNING:popy_file:O gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'O'
INFO:popy_file:Loading v
WARNING:popy_file:v gives error: 
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'v'
INFO:popy_file:Loading e
WARNING:popy_file:e gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'e'
INFO:popy_file:Loading r
WARNING:popy_file:r gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'r'
INFO:popy_file:Loading s
WARNING:popy_file:s gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b's'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading p
WARNING:popy_file:p gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'p'
INFO:popy_file:Loading l
WARNING:popy_file:l gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'l'
INFO:popy_file:Loading I
WARNING:popy_file:i gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'i'
INFO:popy_file:Loading n
WARNING:popy_file:n gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'n'
INFO:popy_file:Loading g
WARNING:popy_file:g gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'g'
INFO:popy_file:Loading _
WARNING:popy_file:_ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'_'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading t
WARNING:popy_file:t gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b't'
INFO:popy_file:Loading l
WARNING:popy_file:l gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'l'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading b
WARNING:popy_file:b gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'b'
INFO:popy_file:Loading -
WARNING:popy_file:- gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'-'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading s
```

WARNING:popy_file:s gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b's'
INFO:popy_file:Loading t
WARNING:popy_file:t gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b't'
INFO:popy_file:Loading e
WARNING:popy_file:e gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'e'
INFO:popy_file:Loading r
WARNING:popy_file:r gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'r'
INFO:popy_file:Loading
WARNING:popy_file:\ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'\'
INFO:popy_file:Loading o
WARNING:popy_file:o gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'o'
INFO:popy_file:Loading v
WARNING:popy_file:v gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'v'
INFO:popy_file:Loading e
WARNING:popy_file:e gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'e'
INFO:popy_file:Loading r
WARNING:popy_file:r gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'r'
INFO:popy_file:Loading s
WARNING:popy_file:s gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b's'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading p
WARNING:popy_file:p gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'p'
INFO:popy_file:Loading l
WARNING:popy_file:l gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'l'
INFO:popy_file:Loading i
WARNING:popy_file:i gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'i'
INFO:popy_file:Loading n
WARNING:popy_file:n gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'n'
INFO:popy_file:Loading g
WARNING:popy_file:g gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'g'
INFO:popy_file:Loading _
WARNING:popy_file:_ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'_'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading t
WARNING:popy_file:t gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b't'
INFO:popy_file:Loading l
WARNING:popy_file:l gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'l'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading b
WARNING:popy_file:b gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'b'
INFO:popy_file:Loading -
WARNING:popy_file:- gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'-'
INFO:popy_file:Loading m
WARNING:popy_file:m gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'm'
INFO:popy_file:Loading a
WARNING:popy_file:a gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'a'
INFO:popy_file:Loading s
WARNING:popy_file:s gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b's'
INFO:popy_file:Loading t
WARNING:popy_file:t gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b't'
INFO:popy_file:Loading e
WARNING:popy_file:e gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'e'
INFO:popy_file:Loading r
WARNING:popy_file:r gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'r'
INFO:popy_file:Loading
WARNING:popy_file:\ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'\'
INFO:popy_file:Loading O
WARNING:popy_file:O gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'O'
INFO:popy_file:Loading M
WARNING:popy_file:M gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'M'
INFO:popy_file:Loading H
WARNING:popy_file:H gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'H'
INFO:popy_file:Loading 2
WARNING:popy_file:2 gives error:
    WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'2'
INFO:popy_file:Loading O
WARNING:popy_file:O gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'O'
INFO:popy_file:Loading
WARNING:popy_file:\ gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'\'
INFO:popy_file:Loading L
WARNING:popy_file:L gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'L'
INFO:popy_file:Loading 2
WARNING:popy_file:2 gives error:
WARNING:popy_file:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'2'
Traceback (most recent call last):`

```
 ` File ~\anaconda3\envs\popy\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\program files (x86)\oversampling_matlab-master\oversampling_matlab-master\oversampling_code.py:35
tmplon = trop_CO.l2g_data['lonc']-trop_CO.west

KeyError: 'lonc'
```

`

I tried to use the same code that fixed the error when analyzing NO2. That code is
`def F_subset_S5PNO2(self,l2_list=None,l2_path_pattern=None,
path=None,data_fields=None,data_fields_l2g=None,
s5p_product='*',
geos_interp_variables=None,geos_time_collection=''):

```
    # Line 5419 to 5435 added to create file list (L2_list)
            path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Oversampling_matlab-master\oversampling_matlab-master\OMH2O\L2'
            import glob
            l2_dir = path
            l2_list = []
        `cwd = os.getcwd()`
       `os.chdir(l2_dir)`
    `start_date = self.start_python_datetime.date()
    ``end_date = self.end_python_datetime.date()`
    `days = (end_date-start_date).days+1`
    `DATES = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in range(days)]`
   ` for DATE in DATES:`
        `flist = glob.glob('S5P_'+s5p_product+'_L2__NO2____'+DATE.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'T*.nc')`
        `l2_list = l2_list+flist`
    `os.chdir(cwd)`
    `self.l2_dir = l2_dir`
    `self.l2_list = l2_list`
    `path = None `
    
    `geos_interp_variables = geos_interp_variables or []`
    # find out list of l2 files to subset
    `if path is not None:
        self.logger.warning('please use l2_list or l2_path_pattern instead')
        import glob
        l2_dir = path
        l2_list = []
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(l2_dir)
        start_date = self.start_python_datetime.date()
        end_date = self.end_python_datetime.date()
        days = (end_date-start_date).days+1
        DATES = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in range(days)]`
        `for DATE in DATES:
            flist = glob.glob('S5P_'+s5p_product+'_L2__NO2____'+DATE.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'T*.nc')
            l2_list = l2_list+flist
        ``os.chdir(cwd)`
        `self.l2_dir = l2_dir`
        `self.l2_list = l2_list`
    `else:
        if l2_list is None and l2_path_pattern is None:
            self.logger.error('either l2_list or l2_path_pattern has to be provided!')
            return
        if l2_list is not None and l2_path_pattern is not None:
            self.logger.info('both l2_list and l2_path_pattern are provided. l2_path_pattern will be overwritten')
            l2_path_pattern = None`
        
      `  if l2_list is None:
            import glob
            l2_list = []
            start_date = self.start_python_datetime.date()
            end_date = self.end_python_datetime.date()
            days = (end_date-start_date).days+1
            DATES = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in range(days)]
            for DATE in DATES:
                flist = glob.glob(DATE.strftime(l2_path_pattern))
                l2_list = l2_list+flist                 
        self.l2_list = l2_list`
   ` maxsza = self.maxsza
    maxcf = self.maxcf
    west = self.west
    east = self.east
    south = self.south
    north = self.north
    min_qa_value = self.min_qa_value
   ` 
    `if not data_fields:
        # default, absolute path of useful variables in the nc file
        data_fields = ['/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/DETAILED_RESULTS/cloud_fraction_crb_nitrogendioxide_window',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/latitude_bounds',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/longitude_bounds',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/solar_zenith_angle',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/viewing_zenith_angle',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/INPUT_DATA/surface_albedo_nitrogendioxide_window',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/INPUT_DATA/surface_pressure',\
                       '/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/INPUT_DATA/surface_altitude',\
                       '/PRODUCT/latitude',\
                       '/PRODUCT/longitude',\
                       '/PRODUCT/qa_value',\
                       '/PRODUCT/time_utc',\
                       '/PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column',\
                       '/PRODUCT/nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column_precision',
                       '/PRODUCT/averaging_kernel',
                       '/PRODUCT/air_mass_factor_troposphere',
                       '/PRODUCT/air_mass_factor_total']    `
    `if not data_fields_l2g:
        # standardized variable names in l2g file. should map one-on-one to data_fields
        data_fields_l2g = ['cloud_fraction','latitude_bounds','longitude_bounds','SolarZenithAngle',\
                           'vza','albedo','surface_pressure','surface_altitude','latc','lonc','qa_value','time_utc',\
                           'column_amount','column_uncertainty','avk','amf_trop','amf_total']
    self.logger.info('Read, subset, and store level 2 data to l2g_data')
    l2g_data = {}`
    `for fn in l2_list:
        self.logger.info('Loading '+os.path.split(fn)[-1])
        fn_dir = os.path.join(l2_dir,fn)  # Added, 7/27/23
```

try:
#outp_nc = self.F_read_S5P_nc(fn,data_fields,data_fields_l2g)    # original
outp_nc = self.F_read_S5P_nc(fn_dir,data_fields,data_fields_l2g) # added 7/27/23
except Exception as e:
self.logger.warning(fn+' gives error:');
self.logger.warning(e)
continue
if geos_interp_variables != []:
sounding_interp = F_interp_geos_mat(outp_nc['lonc'],outp_nc['latc'],outp_nc['UTC_matlab_datenum'],
geos_dir='/mnt/Data2/GEOS/s5p_interp/',
interp_fields=geos_interp_variables,
time_collection=geos_time_collection)
for var in geos_interp_variables:
outp_nc[var] = sounding_interp[var]
f1 = outp_nc['SolarZenithAngle'] <= maxsza
f2 = outp_nc['cloud_fraction'] <= maxcf
# ridiculously, qa_value has a scale_factor of 0.01. so error-prone
f3 = outp_nc['qa_value'] >= min_qa_value
f4 = outp_nc['latc'] >= south
f5 = outp_nc['latc'] <= north
tmplon = outp_nc['lonc']-west
tmplon[tmplon < 0] = tmplon[tmplon < 0]+360
f6 = tmplon >= 0
f7 = tmplon <= east-west
f8 = outp_nc['UTC_matlab_datenum'] >= self.start_matlab_datenum
f9 = outp_nc['UTC_matlab_datenum'] <= self.end_matlab_datenum
validmask = f1 & f2 & f3 & f4 & f5 & f6 & f7 & f8 & f9
self.logger.info('You have '+'%s'%np.sum(validmask)+' valid L2 pixels')
l2g_data0 = {}
# calculate surface avk
# https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/documents/247904/2474726/Sentinel-5P-Level-2-Product-User-Manual-Nitrogen-Dioxide.pdf, section 8.8
if 'avk' in outp_nc.keys():
l2g_data0['avk0'] = outp_nc['avk'][...,0][validmask]/outp_nc['amf_trop'][validmask]*outp_nc['amf_total'][validmask]
# yep it's indeed messed up
Lat_lowerleft = np.squeeze(outp_nc['latitude_bounds'][:,:,0])[validmask]
Lat_upperleft = np.squeeze(outp_nc['latitude_bounds'][:,:,3])[validmask]
Lat_lowerright = np.squeeze(outp_nc['latitude_bounds'][:,:,1])[validmask]
Lat_upperright = np.squeeze(outp_nc['latitude_bounds'][:,:,2])[validmask]
Lon_lowerleft = np.squeeze(outp_nc['longitude_bounds'][:,:,0])[validmask]
Lon_upperleft = np.squeeze(outp_nc['longitude_bounds'][:,:,3])[validmask]
Lon_lowerright = np.squeeze(outp_nc['longitude_bounds'][:,:,1])[validmask]
Lon_upperright = np.squeeze(outp_nc['longitude_bounds'][:,:,2])[validmask]
l2g_data0['latr'] = np.column_stack((Lat_lowerleft,Lat_upperleft,Lat_upperright,Lat_lowerright))
l2g_data0['lonr'] =       np.column_stack((Lon_lowerleft,Lon_upperleft,Lon_upperright,Lon_lowerright))
for key in outp_nc.keys():
if key not in {'latitude_bounds','longitude_bounds','time_utc','time','delta_time',
'avk'}:
l2g_data0[key] = outp_nc[key][validmask]
l2g_data = self.F_merge_l2g_data(l2g_data,l2g_data0)
self.l2g_data = l2g_data
if not l2g_data:
self.nl2 = 0
else:
self.nl2 = len(l2g_data['latc'])

```
    def F_subset_S5PHCHO(self,l2_list=None,l2_path_pattern=None,
                         path=None,data_fields=None,data_fields_l2g=None,
                         s5p_product='*',geos_interp_variables=None,
                         geos_time_collection=''):
```

I tried to change some of the varaibles so it would pertain to CO but it gave me this error

```
runfile('C:/Program Files (x86)/Oversampling_matlab-master/Oversampling_matlab-master/Oversampling_code.py', wdir='C:/Program Files (x86)/Oversampling_matlab-   master/Oversampling_matlab-master')
Reloaded modules: popy_file
INFO:popy_file:creating an instance of popy
INFO:popy_file:Read, subset, and store level 2 data to l2g_data
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\popy\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\program files (x86)\oversampling_matlab-master\oversampling_matlab-master\oversampling_code.py:35
    tmplon = trop_CO.l2g_data['lonc']-trop_CO.west

KeyError: 'lonc'``
```